How to fix unwanted space at the top of the screen?
I'm building a film catalog app. I have a problem with the UI. When I use a tabbar, a space appears on the top of my screen.
How can I fix this problem?
import UIKit

class TabbarViewController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
        
        let vc1 = ListMovieViewController()
        let vc2 = SearchViewController()
        
        vc1.title = "List"
        vc2.title = "Search"
        
        vc1.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        vc2.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        
        let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)
        let nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc2)
        
        nav1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "List", image: UIImage(systemName:  "film"), tag: 1)
        nav2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Search", image: UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass"), tag: 1)
        
        nav1.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        nav2.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        setViewControllers([nav1,nav2], animated: false)
    }
}

import UIKit

class ListMovieViewController: UIViewController {
    private let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableVw = UITableView()
        tableVw.register(FilmCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "FilmCell")
        return tableVw
    }()
    
    private var filmViewModels: FilmViewModels = FilmViewModels()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //NavBar
        title = "Catalog"
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        SetUp()
    }
    
    private func SetUp(){
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.frame = view.bounds

    }
}

extension ListMovieViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filmViewModels.getLength()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FilmCell", for: indexPath) as! FilmCell
        let film = filmViewModels.films[indexPath.row]
        
        let imageUrl = film.imageUrl
        cell.filmImageView.downloaded(from: imageUrl)
        cell.titleLabel.text = film.title
        cell.directorLable.text = "Director by \(film.director)"
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 130
    }
}



Start by changing ListMovieViewController to extend UITableViewController instead of UIViewController. No need to create your own table view. But if you have a reason, at least set proper constraints on the table view.

You also need to update your question showing how you create and setup your instance of TabbarViewController. Are you putting it in its own nav controller?

If you set up your TabBars like this in SceneDelegate, I think the problem will be resolved.
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        // Create the main window
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.rootViewController = createTabBar()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    
    func createTabBar() -> UITabBarController {
        let tabBar = UITabBarController()
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .label
        tabBar.viewControllers = [createFirstVC(), createSecondVC()]
        return tabBar
    }
    
    func createFirstVC() -> UINavigationController {
        let firstVC = FirstViewController()
        firstVC.title = "List"
        firstVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "List", image: UIImage(systemName: "film"), tag: 0)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC)
    }
    
    func createSecondVC() -> UINavigationController {
        let secondVC = SecondViewController()
        secondVC.title = "Search"
        secondVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Search", image: UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass"), tag: 1)
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
    }
}


You are using the wrong UIWindow initializer. Use window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene) instead.

While your code is likely correct in general, your answer makes no attempt to explain what is wrong with the OP's code.
